# checkout page suddenly stop working

Tags: magento-1.9

In my checkout page suddenly stop working i don't know what is the problem after click Place Order it's keep on loading only.

It's default checkout only not any 3rd party module

What is the problem any idea about that

Comment: can you provide more details? How are we supposed to guess what's wrong.

Comment: check in `console` what error showing and also check error log for error.

Comment: No error in consolve related to checkout check this http://www.anaqa.ae/staging2/checkout/onepage/index/

Comment: Check the contents of var/log/system.log and var/log/exception.log within the root of the installation (I don't mean the Linux /var/log folder)